# SherlockActionBar in a MapActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, mapactivity

I'm using the Sherlock Action Bar extensively throughout my application, but I have an activity which inherits from a MapActivity, and thus I can't make it inherits from SherlockActivity.

Is there any way I can make use of the Sherlock Action Bar in the map so I can customize it?

Best,
Manuel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to download the Map plugin:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/downloads