# Issue with Multiple inheritance

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application which contain 2 Tab with Fragment.each Tab class `AssetsMapFragment` and `AssetsListFragment` Extends with `SherlockFragment` class, now i need to extends MapActivity in this both Tab Class but according to Java Multiple Inheritance are not supported. and there are another solution with Interface,that i can make interface and implement with it.but my MapActivity is not interface so i cant able to do that. so can you please give some alternate solution for this situation that what i do to use both class in one class ?thats great help for me.thanks.

Comment: May be you are looking for adapter pattern...

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11341748/1321873

Comment: If your talking about google apis MapActivity, it doesn't support fragments.

Comment: @Zzokk I am Not use Google Map ,I am Use Mapsforge Opensource library

Answer (score 0):

If possible try like this

```
public class a {
public static String a="This is a";
public static void aDisplay()
{
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
public class b {
public static String b="This is b";
public static void bDisplay()
{
    System.out.println(b);
}
}
public class c extends a {
public static class d extends b{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    aDisplay();
    bDisplay();
    }
}
}
```

Using **Inner Class concept** we can solve the problem. Or in the other way you have to follow Multilevel Inheritance only.

Comment: but how can i get instance of MapActivity here is the problem

Comment: class e extends c{
 public static class f extends MapActivity{
  //Your code Here
  //You can access mapActivity here, without creating instance
  //This class e contains all the properties of a,b and MapActivity
  //This is similar to multiple inheritance
 }
}